# SQL Server - 'AS' option in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am trying to execute the following SQL command on SQL Server:

```
   select a1, 
           a2,
    ....
            (select [dbo].[myFunction](a1, a2)) as mySelector
    where mySelector = @sel
```

The error message says:invalid column name mySelector

I tried also "as 'mySelector'" - the same error  message

Any ideas why?

Thanks,

zb

Comment: You can't use an alias in a where condition

Comment: If you care about performance, you shouldn't put an inline function in the where clause either

Comment: You *can* use an alias in a where condition (e.g. as introduced in a JOIN) .. what you can't do is use the result of the select clause from the same statement. This is, well, because the *output* "comes after" any *conditional* in the given SELECT statement.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to filter on the result of your function and use the alias, then you will want to look at using a subquery:

```
select a1, a2, mySelector
from
(
   select a1, 
           a2,
    ....
            (select [dbo].[myFunction](a1, a2)) as mySelector
   from yourtable
) d
where mySelector = @sel;
```

The alias that you are using in the SELECT list is not available in the WHERE clause.  From [MSDN: Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

> The following steps show the logical
>   processing order, or binding order,
>   for a SELECT statement. This order
>   determines when the objects defined in
>   one step are made available to the
>   clauses in subsequent steps. For
>   example, if the query processor can
>   bind to (access) the tables or views
>   defined in the FROM clause, these
>   objects and their columns are made
>   available to all subsequent steps. 
>   Conversely, because the SELECT clause
>   is step 8, any column aliases or
>   derived columns defined in that clause
>   cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be
>   referenced by subsequent clauses such
>   as the ORDER BY clause. Note that the
>   actual physical execution of the
>   statement is determined by the query
>   processor and the order may vary from
>   this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP